# Category filtering in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hey guys I'm currently trying to resolve why my legacy code doesn't work the way it was intended to do so. It's a basic category filter.
My current problem is that I don't really know what to fix.

I tried changing up `whereHas`, `whereIn`, `orWhere` query statement.
When I changed `orWhere` to just simply `where`, the filter worked only if one category was selected.

If anyone has any ideas to fix my problem, help would be gladly appreciated.

My code is below :

Backend(InternController.php) :

```php
$intern = Intern::query()->with('category');
if ($request->categories) {
    $intern->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($intern, $request) {
        foreach ($request->categories as $category) {
            $query->orWhere('category_id', $category);
        }
        $query->whereIn('category_id', $request->categories);
    });
}
$intern = $intern->get();
$categories = Category::all();
$category_intern = CategoryIntern::all();
return view('intern')->with($viewData)->with([
    'intern' => $intern,
    'categories' => $categories,
    'category_intern' => $category_intern,
]);
```

Frontend(intern.blade.php):

```html
 <form method="GET">
    <div class="mx-4">
        <label for="select2Multiple" class="h3 pt-5 ml-auto">
        Categories
        </label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-2 mt-xl-1">
                <select
                    class="select2-multiple form-control"
                    style="min-height: 70px"
                    name="categories[]"
                    multiple="multiple"
                    id="select2Multiple"
                    >
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option
                value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ collect(request()->categories)->contains($category->id) ? "selected": ''}}>
                {{ $category->name }}
                </option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2">
                <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-uppercase font-semibold mt-1 "
                    style="background-color: #0d5eff; min-height: 32px"
                    >Choose category
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, finally.

Deleted the foreach statement in the whereHas body.

final code looks like this

```
$intern = Intern::query()->with('category');
        if ($request->categories) {
            $intern->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($intern, $request) {
                $query->whereIn('category_id', $request->categories);
            });
        }
        $intern = $intern->get();
```